# Is it possible deploy an app with worklight enabled to receive notifications from multiple servers id?

Tags: android, notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

we want deploy an app  ( a wallet ) using worklight that must be able to register to GCM with multiple sender id (just two), this to enable it to receive notifications from two servers: the first server run a service that have a counterpart in a sdk build up in the app/wallet , the second server run a whole container ( a wallet ) hosting many services. Among these services there is also the service deployed with the sdk above mentioned and related to the first server.

I read that GCM enable this muntiple senders id registrations but I'm not sure that worklight is able to work in this way.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in MobileFirst. You can try submitting a request for enhancement here:

[Request for enhancement](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/)